# React.js - TODO List edit button not working

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, edit

I am new to React.js and trying to create a TODO list. I have two buttons for edit and delete. Delete button is working fine, but not the edit button. I am having a hard time with Edit button. When I click on the edit button, I want the text box to be editable. Then I can edit and when I enter, it should be updated.

I have some css issue with button alignments too. Please help me with this.

[image]

App.js

---

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import './AddedTasks.css'
import uuid from 'uuid'

class App extends React.Component{

   constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        task:[],
        currentTask:{
            text:'',
            key:''
        }
    }
    this.addTask = this.addTask.bind(this);
    this.editTask = this.editTask.bind(this);
    this.deleteTask = this.deleteTask.bind(this);
    this.handleInput = this.handleInput.bind(this);
}
addTask(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    const newItem = this.state.currentTask;
    if(newItem.text !==""){
        const items = [...this.state.task, newItem];
        this.setState({
            task: items,
            currentTask:{
                text:'',
                key:''
            },
        })
    }
}
editTask(text,key) {
    //console.log("items:"+this.state.task);
     const items = this.state.task;
     items.map(item=>{
         if(item.key===key){
             //console.log(item.key +"    "+key)
             // item.text= text.title;
         }
     })
     this.setState({
         task: items,
     })
}
deleteTask(key){
    const currentTaskArray = [...this.state.task]
    const taskAfterDeleted = currentTaskArray.filter(deletedTask => deletedTask.key !== key);
    this.setState({
        task:taskAfterDeleted
    })
}
handleInput(event){
    this.setState({
        currentTask:{
            text: event.target.value,
            key: uuid()
        }
    })
}
render(){
  return(
      <div className='Todo'>
          <h1> MyTaskList </h1>
          <form id="todo-list" onSubmit={this.addTask}>
              <input type="text" className="textInput" placeholder="Enter Item" value={this.state.currentTask.text} onChange={this.handleInput}/>
              <button type ="submit">Add</button>
          </form>
          {this.state.task.map(oneTask=>(
              <div className="card">
                  <div className="container">
                      <p>{oneTask.text}
                        <div>
                            <button className="w3-button delete" onClick={()=> this.deleteTask(oneTask.key)}><i className="fa fa-trash"/></button>
                              <button className="w3-button edit" onClick={(edit)=>this.editTask(edit.target.value,oneTask.key)}><i className="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"/></button>
                        </div>
                      </p>
                  </div>
              </div>
          ))}
      </div>
    );
   }
  }
  export default App;


  App.css
 _______________

body{
 background-color: lightblue;
 background-image: url("./todolist.jpg");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 alignment: center;
 padding-top: 40px;
}
 h1{
    text-align: center;
    color: #bf6318;
    padding-right: 17px;
}
.Todo{
    background-color: #c1b2cd;
    min-height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 150px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    background-image: url("./pin.jpg");
    background-size: 80px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
  #todo-list input{
      background-color: rgb(95, 83, 135);
      border: 0;
      width: 250px;
      height: 50px;
      padding: 0 20px;
      margin: 20px;
      font-size: 18px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      color: #ffffff;
   }
   #todo-list input::placeholder{
      color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
   }
   button{
       background-color: #008CBA;
       border: none;
       color: white;
       padding: 15px 32px;
       text-align: center;
       text-decoration: none;
       display: inline-block;
       font-size: 16px;
       margin: 4px 2px;
       cursor: pointer;
      -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
       transition-duration: 0.4s;
       box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.24),0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
   }


  AddedTask.cs
  _________________


  .card {
     box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
     transition: 0.3s;
     width: 70%;
     border-radius: 5px;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
     margin-left: 20px;
     background-color: #bf826b;
  }
  .card:hover {
     box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  }
  .container {
     padding: 4px 16px;   /*input/card field*/
     height: 40px;
  }
 .container button.edit{
      color: #bf6318;
      margin-left: 80px;
      margin-right: 10px;
  }
  .container button.delete{

   }
```

Comment: Other than obvious html syntax issues, are you trying to make the `<p>{oneTask.text}` an editable field? I.E. you want to toggle the `<p>` to an `<input>` and when you hit enter or something it saves what you entered and switches back to a `<p>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The edit button is not working because you are using `edit.target.value` which doesn't exist. In my understanding, you are trying to access the text so it will be `oneTask.text`.

Here is the file:

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import uuid from "uuid";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      task: [],
      currentTask: {
        text: "",
        key: ""
      }
    };
    this.addTask = this.addTask.bind(this);
    this.editTask = this.editTask.bind(this);
    this.deleteTask = this.deleteTask.bind(this);
    this.handleInput = this.handleInput.bind(this);
  }
  addTask(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const newItem = this.state.currentTask;
    if (newItem.text !== "") {
      const items = [...this.state.task, newItem];
      this.setState({
        task: items,
        currentTask: {
          text: "",
          key: ""
        }
      });
    }
  }
  editTask(text, key) {
    //console.log("items:"+this.state.task);
    const items = this.state.task;

    this.setState({
      task: items.filter(item => item.key !== key),
      currentTask: {
        text
      }
    });
  }
  deleteTask(key) {
    const currentTaskArray = [...this.state.task];
    const taskAfterDeleted = currentTaskArray.filter(
      deletedTask => deletedTask.key !== key
    );
    this.setState({
      task: taskAfterDeleted
    });
  }
  handleInput(event) {
    this.setState({
      currentTask: {
        text: event.target.value,
        key:uuid()
      }
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Todo">
        <h1> MyTaskList </h1>
        <form id="todo-list" onSubmit={this.addTask}>
          <input
            type="text"
            className="textInput"
            placeholder="Enter Item"
            value={this.state.currentTask.text}
            onChange={this.handleInput}
          />
          <button type="submit">Add</button>
        </form>
        {this.state.task.map(oneTask => (
          <div key={oneTask.key} className="card">
            <div className="container">
              <p>
                {oneTask.text}
                <div>
                  <button
                    className="w3-button delete"
                    onClick={() => this.deleteTask(oneTask.key)}
                  >
                    Delete
                  </button>
                  <button
                    className="w3-button edit"
                    onClick={() => this.editTask(oneTask.text, oneTask.key)}
                  >
                    Edit
                  </button>
                </div>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

I have also manipulated the edit task code you can revert back to use your code.

Here is the working link: https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-almeida-uivq0

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Yash ! https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-shaw-zxoiq.  Striking the text once a task is done (3rd button) and then taking the striked task to the bottom of the list is not working. Can you help me with this ?

Comment: Hey Prasadika, can you please elaborate and give a correct sandbox link

Comment: Hi Yash ! https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-gauss-s12bf. Please use this sandbox link, sorry about the previous one. 3rd button wants to be able to strike a text and when it does strike, that particular task should go to the bottom of the list. so it becomes the last item of the list and the rest of the items only push up allowing that item to go to the bottom. Thanks in advance

Comment: The other thing is when I add an item with the "Add" button, it should be added to the top, not to the bottom like it is happening now.

Comment: Hey Prasadika, can you tell me what you have tried and what is not working for you ?

Comment: Hi Yash ! Could you please be online for a few mins ? I will send you the updates sandbox link. I've got everything working fine except for 2 things. I want to strike the item upon clicking "Done" button". After striking through, it should disable/hide the "Edit" button. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey @Prasadika I am not sure where are you facing the issue and what is the issue. But here is the link which may help you: https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-feather-bl2jf
. Also please do things by yourself instead of asking, if you want to learn about react/JS do shoot me a message. I will share the links. Thanks

Comment: Hi Yash ! Thank You so much. Even though it wasn't what I wanted exactly, It helped me a lot. I managed to do what I want with the help of that.  Thanks so much. Yes, please. Could you please share some materials with which I can learn React ? I am a beginner in React.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm assuming that this is a view of todo and by default it's disabled. You can use a state variable to make textboxes enabled when clicking on the edit button.
Add a handler to edit button click event and inside this handler change state variable. So react will enable those two textboxes based on that event.

```
this.state = {
isEditable:false // by defualt this is disables
}

editHandler(){
//change isEditable to true
}
```

Make sure to bind this new method in constructor. Then add this to the button click event.
Base on isEditable makes your form controls enabled or disabled.

Regarding CSS, just use a new div element and inside that div include two buttons. So it won't come to on top of text boxes.

```
<div>
  <div>text box and button</div>
  <div>second row</div>
  <div>edit and delete button></div>
</div>
```